# Get comma separated value from multiple row in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have this table

> ```
> Cream
> ----------
> CHOCALATE
> GREEN
> TEST
> ```

want out put in select query like this

### cream

CHOCALATE,GREEN,TEST

Comment: Yeah it looks like most of the questions you asked have been answered satisfactory, so just select an answer..

Answer (score 6):

With sysobjects this worked:

```
DECLARE @List varchar(2000)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') + Cast(name As varchar(50))
FROM sys.sysobjects

SELECT @List As 'List'
```

Comment: brilliant, simply brilliant. I have always went down the aggregate UDF path before but this solution relies on sequential evaluation of the variable expressions!

Answer (score 4):

I found a useful resource [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string) when I needed to do this, but as the others said, use COALESCE...

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ', '') + Name
FROM Cream

SELECT @List
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [coalesce](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is to create an aggregate user defined function and register it on the database.

Try here for an example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165055.aspx

Your query would look like "SELECT dbo.Concatenate(Field) FROM Cream"

You will be returned what you expect "a,b,c,d..."  ect.