# Merge Multiple Data from Rows/Records into One Row w/ Comma Separated Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I were to query our ORDERS table, I might enter the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM ORDERS
 WHERE ITEM_NAME = 'Fancy Pants'
```

In the results for this query, I might get the following:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 ORDER_ID       WAIST       First_Name       Email
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 001            32          Jason            j-diddy[at]some-thing.com
 005            28          Pip              pirrip[at]british-mail.com
 007            28          HAL9000          olhal[at]hot-mail.com
```

Now, I'm also wanting to pull information from a different table:

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE ITEM_NAME = 'Fancy Pants'

```
 ------------------------------------------
 PRODUCT_ID     Product       Prod_Desc
 ------------------------------------------
 008            Fancy Pants   Really fancy.
```

In the end, however, I'm actually wanting to condense these records into one row via SQL query:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PRODUCT       ORDER_Merged  First_Name_Merged  Email_Merged
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Fancy Pants   001,005,007   Jason,Pip,Hal9000  j-di[...].com, pirrip[...].com
```

Anyway, that's how it would look. What I can't figure out is what that "merge" query would look like.

My searches here unfortunately keep leading me to results for PHP. I have found a couple of results re: [merging into CSV rows via SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486332/get-comma-separated-value-from-multiple-row-in-sql-server-2005) but I don't think they'll work in my scenario.

Any insight would, as always, be greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE:

Ah, turns out the `STUFF` and `FOR XML` functions were [exactly what I needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787498/tsql-aggregate-string-for-group-by). Thanks all!!

```
 Select
    A.name,
         stuff((
         select ',' + B.address
         from Addresses B
         WHERE A.id=B.name_id
         for xml path('')),1,1,'')
    From Names A
```

Comment: Search for `JOIN`. Trust me, you want to learn this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Comment: This type of  thing has been asked hundreds of times.  We get at least 2 or 3 per week.  Just because an existing question doesn't cover your exact scenario doesn't mean it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @drdwilcox - it's not an issue with the `JOIN` its an issue with concatenating and grouping I think.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005  BTW: Saying something is a duplicate is not a slight against the author; we just don't want to rehash something we know is answered elsewhere.

Comment: @JNK - It has been asked so many times, that someone actually created a tag [group-concat] for it. So, just do a quick search with the tags [sql-server] and [group-concat] and you'll see a lot of answers for this

Comment: Ah, turns out the `STUFF` and `FOR XML` functions were exactly what I needed. Thanks all!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787498/tsql-aggregate-string-for-group-by

`Select
    A.name,
    stuff((
        select ',' + B.address
        from Addresses B
        WHERE A.id=B.name_id
        for xml path('')),1,1,'')
From Names A`

Comment: I think answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29586186/4519059) are what you are looking for ;).

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent article on various approaches to group concatenation with pro's and con's of each.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Personally however, I like the Coalesce approach as I demonstrate here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2615/1607

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. They become useless when the referenced resource disappears. Please take the time to sum up the required steps, so that this answer remains valid in the future.